# How to switch frames using name attribute with wildcards in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, iframe, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I am challenged by this error using Wildcard(*) in a string to locate a frame. When I write the complete name of the iFrame in the statement, it has no issues finding the Frame.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("*_ifr") 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchFrameException: 'No frame element found with name or id *_ifr'
```

When I enter the entire frames name like below,  it works just fine

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("txt-client-instructions_ifr")
```

I expect the wildcard will find the following iframes:

- 1st      `txt-client-instructions_ifr`
- 2nd      `107314_100323_ifr`
- 3rd      `107341_100324_ifr`
- 4th      `100321_macrotext_ifr`

Your thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[`SwitchTo().Frame()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_SwitchTo.htm) is the method to give you access to switch frames and windows. The argument type is of *String*. As an example:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("FrameName");
```

String doesn't support wildcards where as `By.CssSelector` or `By.XPath` supports wildcards.

Hence,

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("txt-client-instructions_ifr")
```

is successful, where as:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("*_ifr")
```

raises *`OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchFrameException`*.

---

### Update

As an alternative you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe[name$='_ifr']")));
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@name, '_ifr')]")));
  ```

Comment: Thanks you for your great feedback something I did not know.  I tried a different statement using xpath , but I still get a no element found.  . is the following still wrong :  driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='*_ifr']")));

Comment: Thanks again! it did work . The first statement below works perfect.  May I ask why the 2nd statement that comes right after it is not working?  I thought once you switch to the frame you want , you can then  access any thing inside it so I used the second statement to add text 
 in the text area but it does not work
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@id, '_ifr')]")));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//#document/html/body")).SendKeys("Your Text Here");

Comment: Many thanks to you. I will